# 2 specific media queries

Tags: html, css, screen, media

Is it possible to use 2 media queries and between this screen size there should be an edit. Let's say you want to use `margin:5px;` between screen size 700px and 500px. I know that you can start with `@media (max-width: 700px) {margin:5px;}` and use `@media (min-width: 500px) {margin:0px;}` after, but.

My question is, is there a code that shortens this?

**NOTE:** TO GIVE YOU AN IDEA OF WHAT I MEAN: `@media (min-width: 700px between 500px){margin:0px;}`

Answer (score 2):

```
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 700px)
```

Comment: isn't min-width used for what happens before this screen size? It would be nice if you could give an explanation.

Comment: Made a mistake. Edited.
You can have a look here :
http://gionaf.com/tools/css3-mediaquery-generator/